# How to write anything in the log if we have thrown out ServletException?

Tags: exception, servlets, log4j

I want to make an entry in the log if my servlet throws ServletException

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
    try {

    } catch (ServletException e) {
        log.warn("error");
        throw new SerletException(e);
    }
```

Will it recurse? Is it the right way to handle exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there will be no recursion, but wrapping the exception in another one is unnecessary. Just throw `e` plain.

```
try {

} catch (ServletException e) {
    log.warn("error");
    throw e;
}
```

By the way, a better place for this is a `Filter` which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/*`, so that you don't need to repeat it in all servlets.

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} catch (ServletException e) {
    log.warn("error");
    throw e;
}
```